# I am Using wordpress and Newspaper theme and wanted to show my posts after click it will open in the new tab

Tags: wordpress

This is the code I have done on `loop.php` but it's not working

```
<h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">
     <a <?php if(!is_user_logged_in()) { echo 'class="lrm-register"'; } ?> href="<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { the_permalink(); } else { echo '#'; } ?>" target="_blank" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute() ?>">
                    <?php the_title() ?>
     </a>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please detail better, adding further information, about why don't working?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just checking, but you do not have a closing h3 tag? I assume that isn't the issue but bring it up anyways.

Comment: This is the code on loop.php I have added target="_blank" but it's not working.
<div class="item-details">
                <h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">
                    <a <?php if(!is_user_logged_in()) { echo 'class="lrm-register"'; } ?> href="<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { the_permalink(); } else { echo '#'; } ?>" target="_blank" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute() ?>">
                        <?php the_title() ?>
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </div>